# C++/CLI How to translate this code ?

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, iplimage

I dont know a lot about C++, but I have to make work some C++ code with .NET. I try with DLLImport but I failed. So I try with C++/CLI to make kind of a wrapper.

But I'm not sure to understand everything...

This is the basic C++ H file with the function I want to export (MyFunction)

```
 extern "C"
 {
  __declspec(dllexport) IplImage* MyFunction(IplImage *src, std::string* name, OneEnumerationType myEnum, bool myBool, float myFloat);
 }
```

This is the Wrapper h code.

```
#include "MyFunction.h"; // the file containing the h code
#include <string>

namespace MyWrapper{
 public ref class MyWrapperClass {
     public: 
       MyWrapper(){};
       IplImage^ GetMyFunction(IplImage *src, std::string^ name, OneEnumerationType myEnum, bool myBool, float myFloat);
}
```

This is the Wrapper cpp code.

```
#include "MyWrapperCode.h";

namespace MyWrapper{
IplImage^ MyWrapperClass::GetMyFunction(IplImage* src, std:string^ name, OneEnumerationType myEnum, bool myBool, float myFloat){
  MyFunction(src, name, myEnum, myBool, myFloat);
 }
}
```

These are my questions :

1) When I'm compiling, the error is "'^ : cannot use this indirection on type IplImage' and same message for type "std::string". 
I have followed this logical :

```
ClasseNative clNat2 = *clNat;  --> ClasseManagee clMan2 = *clMan;
ClasseNative &clNat3 = clNat2; -->  ClasseManagee %clMan3 = clMan2;
ClasseNative *clNat4 = &clNat2; --> ClasseManagee ^clMan4 = %clMan2;
```

I have seen, that It was better to use System::String. I try this way but the initial function is using std::string... BTW, why is it better to change ?

2) How do I get the MyFunction IplImage result ? Thru a private member and a get I suppose but I dont know how to initialize it...

3) Tricky question. Is it possible for me to put the CLI obtains IplImage structure (from the OpenCV library) (the result of my function) inside a IplImage .NET structure, when I ll called my wrapper ? Dont know if the question is understandable...

Thanks a lot for your help. 
Turning around for 3 days on this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper class needs to create a new std::string based on the content of a System::String^ parameter then pass to your native function. Otherwise you need to rewrite the function to take something else as the string input, for example a LPWSTR or LPCSTR.

You can write a ref class to have properties for all data that an IplImage would have, then pass that to your wrapper class.  Your wrapper class then create an IplImage object based on the data of the ref class and pass to the native function. Reverse the data copying direction for the return value.

Comment: So I need to add kind of System::String^ myVar as a private variable ? And how do I transfert data from Std::string to System::String ?

Comment: As a parameter. std:string as a local variable for your function call. Your managed wrapper class consumer doesn't recognize a native std:string.

Answer (score 1):

1) just by adding ^ you cannot change a native object to become managed, you have to create wrappers or transfer the data for example:

```
std::string nativeString = "my string";
String^ managedString = gcnew String(nativeString.c_str());
//now you can return it as
```

2) create a managed wrapper or use primitive datatype to transfer the data

3) note sure if this will help but look at [Emgu.CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation)

try reading abit more about C++\CLI here are a few nice tutorials:

[Quick C++/CLI - Learn C++/CLI in less than 10 minutes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes)

[C++/CLI for the C# programmer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b942f9/cppcli-for-the-C-Sharp-programmer/)

Comment: Thanks for the second link. I already have read the first one.